# Displaying unicode emoji in filenames on Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, unicode, ls, sh, coreutils

I'd like to use emoji in filenames and access them on the command line, but I can't seem to get it to work with `ls`. Weird thing is, if I pipe into just about any other program, the emoji are correctly displayed:

```
$ ls
?  tmp  我很好，谢谢

$ ls --color
?  tmp  我很好，谢谢

$ ls | cat

tmp
我很好，谢谢

$ ls | xargs
 tmp 我很好，谢谢

$ ls | column
               tmp             我很好，谢谢

$ ls | awk '{print $1}'

tmp
我很好，谢谢
```

I'm using GNU coreutils 8.23.

Here's my locale info:

```
[LOCAL] vagrant@vagrant ~$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Anybody know what causes this behaviour, and how I might make a plain 'ol `ls` display something like what `ls | xargs` does in this situation?

Comment: You can address comments only to users that have just posted other comments, or answers, else it will be not delivered... BTW I don't think this behaviour is related with coreutil. Are you using a `sh` shell? It is not a (d)ash or bash one? Which is the output of locale?

Comment: Ah, didn't know that about the comments. I don't believe this is any sort of issue, just observation of behaviour. Coreutil provides the `ls` command on my system.

Comment: You may find interesting this [Q&A](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/187426/66388).  This character () on my browser is different from the one I can see on the mobile telephone...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the `ls` man page.

```
       --show-control-chars
          show non graphic characters as-is (default unless program is 'ls' and output is a terminal)
```

I'd have to look into it further to figure out why the `ls` command is treated specially, but that argument will display  when using `ls`.